# regex to not allow two zeros in the end of a number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I am trying to implement input number field which will not allow if number end with two 0's i.e. if I enter 23100 then it should not allow it. 
I'm using the regex /^[0-9]*00$/ but it allowing 123100.

I have pasted my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/yveekcqw/)

```
enter code here
```

Comment: `00$` is enough to match strings ending in `00`. It's matching numbers *not* ending in `00` that might be more difficult.

Comment: Try `/^(?!\d*00$)\d+$/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew /^(?!\d*00$)\d+$/ is working thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?!\d*00$)\d+$/
```

It will match

- `^`  - start of string
- `(?!\d*00$)` - a negative lookahead that makes sure no 0+ digits followed with `00` at the end are allowed
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `$` - end of string

Answer (score 1):

Updated now to now use look-behinds or look-aheads.

```
^\d*(?:\d?[1-9]|[1-9]\d)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D7tZ1O/5)

Comment: AngularJS is JavaScript, and JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds

Comment: @Aaron Well, you could always use a small web-service to perform your regex match on a server that does (LOL).

Comment: Now it won't match numbers with less than 3 digits. `^\d*(?:\d?[1-9]|[1-9]\d)$` should work though

Comment: @TomWyllie you've missed a `?`, it matches 2-digits numbers but not single-digit ones :)

Comment: Thanks! :) Fixed again, it still doesn't match the single character string `0` but given the other answer is already accepted I am not going to continue tweaking this less elegant regex to perfection. Think we're flogging a dead horse here...

Comment: @TomWyllie I assumed it shouldn't match `0` (which wasn't mentioned by OP, but well `0` and `00` *as numbers* are equivalent). If it should be matched, `^\d*(?:\d?[1-9]|[1-9]?\d)$` should work just fine. And your answer might still be used by someone else landing on this question with a distaste for lookarounds, so I command your effort of editing your answer :)

Comment: @Aaron that pattern you've just commented does indeed allow matching of zeros, but unfortunately also breaks the rest of the pattern by allowing numbers ending in `00` through. However as you say `00` and `0` are equivalent integers so I suppose it's outwith OP's use case.

Answer (score 0):

try this.
`(^\d+[1-9]+0{0,1}$)`

This will work for numbers like

12
123
12310
etc

any number with 2 or more 0's at the end doesn't match in this case

Comment: This won't match numbers with less than two digits though. Also, `0{0,1}` is more usually written `0?`